# How to Fetch the column values from this method?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ienumerable

I have a method which is used to fetch values of 3 columns named ItemNumber,ItemDescription,UnitDescription of a selected row from my table .I have passed a parameter ItemId of that selected row and have to fetch each column value in different variables.I don't know how to work upon it .Can anyone tell me how to do this.Here is my code-

```
  public System.Collections.IEnumerable FetchDataItem(int id)
    {
        var row = (from t1 in context.InventoryUnit
                   join t2 in context.InventoryItem on t1.UnitId equals t2.UnitId
                   where t2.ItemId == id
                   orderby t2.ItemNumber, t2.ItemDescription
                   select new
                  {

                   t2.ItemNumber,
                   t2.ItemDescription,
                    t1.UnitDescription
                  });


        return row.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Be sure to set your return type in your `IEnumerable<T>` as `IEnumerable<YourClass>`

Answer (score 0):

Satpal gave a great example, however if you don't want to create a class you could use this and select it as an anonymous type.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Short example...
    var rows = (from t1 in context.InventoryUnit
                join t2 in context.InventoryItem on t1.UnitId equals t2.UnitId
                where t2.ItemId == id
                orderby t2.ItemNumber, t2.ItemDescription
                select new
                {
                    ItemNumber = t2.ItemNumber,
                    ItemDescription = t2.ItemDescription,
                    UnitDescription = t1.UnitDescription
                 });

    // Here you still have access to data and the types of the data.

    foreach (var row in row)
    {
        // do something with the data....
        var someint = row.ItemNumber;
        var someString = row.ItemDescription;
        var someotherstring = row.ItemDescription;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I assign the the values returned by each column to 3 different variables of type int(for ItemNumber),string(for ItemDescription) and string(for UnitDescription)

Comment: @user2718073 updated. Disregard the statement about returning the `IEnumerable<object>`. You would have to be in the same method to use this.